# Logic behind proving the linear independence of function sets

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

Consider the question sourced [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3171940/why-is-1-x-and-x2-linearly-independent#:%7E:text=because%20if%20some%20linear%20combination,then%20the%20coefficients%20are%20zero.). It is said that $X=\{1, x, x^2 \}$ is proved to be linearly independent by showing the system

$$\mathbb{S}=\begin{cases} a+b+c = 0 \\ a+2b+4c=0 \end{cases}$$

only has solutions $a = b = c = 0$. But what is the logic behind such proof? My interpretation is the following (I will write the logical step I'm unsure about in italics):

> If $X$ were linearly dependent, then there would exist a non-trivial sequence $\{a, b, c\}$ such that $a(1)+bx+cx^2 =0$. *Because such sequence is a solution to the system for any $x$, then it should be a solution to the specific cases $x =1, x = 2$.* Such non-trivial sequence is proven inexistent for such specific cases. Then $X$ is not linearly dependent.

An equivalent reasoning, for example, might be used on the infinite set of functions $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$

$$S' =\{1, n, n^2,... \}$$

One might show this system is linearly independent by assuming it is not. Then some $\{x_i, ..., x_r\}$ is a non-trivial solution to the system

\begin{equation*}
    x_in^i + x_jn^j + ... + x_rn^r = 0 
\end{equation*}

Then it is a non-trivial solutions for the specific cases $n = 1, n = 2$, such that

\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{S} = \begin{cases}
        x_i + x_j + ... + x_r = 0 \\
        x_i2^i + x_j2^j + ... + x_r2^r = 0
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}

It can be proved that no solution to this system exists other than $x_i = ... = x_r = 0$, which then implies $\{1, n, n^2, ... \}$ is LI.

Is this the correct interpretation of this method of proving a set of functions, finite or infinite, is linearly independent? That is, to notice that if the linear combination of the functions $f_1, ..., f_k$ can non-trivially be $0$ with coefficients $\{a, b, ..., k \}$, then such set of coefficients should make the linear combination of any specific values taken by this functions $0$ as well. In other words, they would also be solutions to

$$\begin{cases}af_1(x_1) + ... +kf(x_1) &= 0 \\ af(x_2) + ... +kf(x_2) &=0 \\ ... \\ af_1(x_k) + ...+ kf(x_k) &= 0 \end{cases}$$

with $x_1, ..., x_k$ arbitrary values in the domain of $f_1, ..., f_k$. Then showing such non-trivial solution to this system does *not* exist, one shows the set can not be linearly dependent.

Comment: I think you need to consider more values, e.g. if the supposed counterexample in $x_i,\cdots,x_r$ has $k$ elements, then you should consider $x=1,x=2,x=3,\cdots,x=k-1$. This boils down to Van Der Monde's determinant

Comment: In total generality, the world of linear spaces is huge. There is no one method that is appropriate for all situations.

Comment: @FShrike typo: you certainly intended to begin with x=0, not 1

Comment: Actually, *none* of the answers to that question claim that the only solution of the system $\Bbb S$ is $(a,b,c)=(0,0,0)$, which is good, since that assertion is false. In fact, for any real number $\lambda$, the triplet $(2\lambda,-3\lambda,\lambda)$ is a solution.

Comment: Indeed, this corresponds to FShrike's first first comment above (appart from the typo): for $k$ vectors, you have $k$ coefficients to annihilate hence you need $k$ equations, so here $k$ instances of $x.$ Note however that in the linked post, the question was about "linear independence of functions like $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x) = x$" hence *all* the answers were correct, but our OP interpreted them wrongly.

Comment: lafinur Reasoning by contradiction is unnecessary. You can as well directly say: let us prove that $1,x,x^2$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb R,$i.e. that$$\forall(a,b,c)\in\Bbb R^3\quad(a+bx+cx^2=0\Rightarrow a=b=c=0).$$So, let $(a,b,c)\in\Bbb R^3$ be such that $a+bx+cx^2=0.$ Then, $a+b+c=a+2b+4c=a+3b+9c=0,$ hence [...] $a=b=c=0,$ q.e.d.

Comment: Last remark: if the ground field was $K=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ (the field with only two elements $0$ and $1$, where $2=1+1=0$) instead of $\Bbb R,$, the *functions* $t\mapsto 1,t\mapsto t,t\mapsto t^2$ would not be independent any longer (because the third one equals the first one). The *polynomials* would still be independent but the method used here would not work.